# Setting little app icon in iOS in .NET MAUI app

Tags: maui, .net-maui

All the app icons in my .NET MAUI app seem to work correctly, except for this little guy on iOS. You see this icon when you swipe up to see all the open apps.

[image]

I guess, somehow I'm missing this but I uploaded all the icons with different sizes Apple requires for iOS apps. Which one is this icon and how do I make sure I'm giving Apple my app's icon for this particular size so it doesn't default to the .NET icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,this is often the case when you are using images that are not formatted correctly or are very complex.  And I've had similar problems before.

Vector graphics are highly recommended in ios.